# mdf file not visible in App_Data folder, Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am new to Web Development in ASP .NET using Microsoft Visual Studio. I am trying to set up my database following an online tutorial which uses the Code First technique of Entity Framework to define the database.

I have creating the classes in the Models Folder.

I edited the Web.config file as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data
Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WingtipToys-
20131119102907.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WingtipToys-20131119102907;Integrated
Security=True" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="OddJobs"
     connectionString="Data 
Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\oddjobs.mdf;Integra
ted Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
  </connectionStrings>
```

OddJobs is the name of my application. I haven't edited anything in the first add tag. I have put in 'OddJobs' in the second tag wherever necessary. The application builds successfully. However, I cannot view my .mdf file after debugging the application. I have tried refreshing the App_Data folder and 'showing all files'. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure the DB is in that folder? When you go to your project's folder on your computer can you see the DB in that folder?

Comment: No, I cannot see the database in the project's folder on my computer.

Comment: That's why it doesn't appear in that folder when you refresh or show all files. Did you use a wizard to create a connection to your DB? If so in one of the steps there should be a checkbox that prompts if you want to save a copy of the DB to your project or something like that. I just don't remember where exactly but tick it if you find it    . It will save a copy to your App_Data folder then you'll be able to see it. I just wish I had something opened in front of me so I can give you direct steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the db version from `(LocalDB)\v11.0;` to `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;`. It worked for me on Visual 2017.